# Converting non-numeric integers in column that also contains strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like the junk column below:

```
d = {'Junk Column' : ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', 'J', 'K'],
 'Good Column' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 'J', 'K']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

  Good Column   Junk Column
0   1       1
1   2       2
2   3       3
3   4       4
4   5       5
5   6       6
6   7       7
7   J       J
8   K       K
```

My goal is to get to the Good Column. The difference is that '1' has been converted to 1.

```
df['Junk Column'] = df['Junk Column'].astype(int)
```

fails because 'J' and 'K' cannot be converted to an integer..

I've successfully converted the junk column to the good column using:

```
def clean_out_strings(value):
    try:
        return int(value)
    except ValueError:
        return value

df['Junk Column'] = df['Junk Column'].apply(clean_out_strings)
```

However, since my dataframe is >1mil rows, and is growing everyday, this is pretty slow. I wanted to see if someone has a faster way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be faster:

```
>>> df
  good     junk
0    1     1.25  # a float
1    2        2  # already an int
2    3       +3
3    4       -4  # signed
4    5       5   # leading/trailing space
5    6        6
6    7     7   
7    J      J 3
8    K       K5
>>> df['junk'].values
array([1.25, 2, '+3', '-4', ' 5 ', '6', '   7   ', 'J 3', 'K5'], dtype=object)
>>> i = df['junk'].str.strip().str.match(r'[+-]?\d+', na=True)
>>> df.loc[i, 'junk'] = df.loc[i, 'junk'].astype('int')
>>> df['junk'].values
array([1, 2, 3, -4, 5, 6, 7, 'J 3', 'K5'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: I'm willing to bet this will be faster. When I use it though, i.unique() results in array([nan, False], dtype=object) which then throws ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values in the df.loc[] line

Comment: @DataSwede that means you have non string values mixed in; you need to specify `na=True` or `na=False` depending on what those values are. see my edits.